# Webpack cannot resolve modules from subdirectory of a package

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a package that is being built to a directory named `lib`. The structure is as follows:

```
- lib/
-- moduleA/
---- index.js
-- moduleB/
---- index.js
- src/
-- moduleA/
-- moduleB/
```

and in `package.json` I specify:

```
"main": "./lib"
```

In a different project, I'm trying to import a specific module from the package above, as follows:

```
import moduleA from '@scope/packageA/moduleA';
```

but Webpack is not able to resolve the module, saying:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@scope/packageA/moduleA'

However, it does work if I import directly from `lib`:

```
import moduleA from '@scope/packageA/lib/moduleA;
```

Why is this happening? my understanding is the Webpack respects the `main` entry of the package, and that it should be possible to import from anywhere in the hierarchy starting from the entry point.

Comment: [main](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) is just a pointer to a single entry point file though: `@scope/packageA/lib/index.js` presumably. It cannot be a directory, therefore you cannot add a path to the import and expect it to be resolved relative to it. Your second `import` is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a few years late, but if someone needs a possible answer for this:

You can use the `exports` field inside `package.json` to define which directories resolve to which modules, using the example in the question, you might want to have something like this:

```json
// package.json
{
  ...
  "exports": {
    "./moduleA": "./lib/moduleA/index.js",
    "./moduleB": "./lib/moduleB/index.js",
  },
}
```

This will help Node to correctly resolve the package import, and "translate" it from:

```js
import moduleA from '@scope/packageA/moduleA';
```

to:

```js
import moduleA from '@scoppe/packageA/lib/moduleA/index.js';
```

Note that this works for Node v12+, any version before will use the `main` field as the entry for your package.

There's a lot more to this because you can specify entry points conditionally and use them for builds with different Javascript formats (CommonJS and EMS), be sure to check out the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points)